# Phonegap + Cordova + Firebase + Push Notification +iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, phonegap

i'm new in the world of certificates, and reading aware i had to adapt my flow to various case posted but without resolve the problem as per my current configuration.

Can you please confirm me the flow to produce the certificate app rightly ?

**WHAT WAS DONE**

**App ID creation**

1. Create an App ID (ex. com.dir.app)
2. Enable for app ID com.dir.app the push certification

**Development APNS creation**

3. [keychain] - produce a pair of key by a Certification request (key pair name: com.dir.app.dev)
4. [dev.console] - upload certificate SSL for the dev push part inside App ID options
5. Download the certificate com.dir.app.dev.apns.cer
6. Open it and export it as com.dir.app.dev.apns.p12

**Development certificate creation**

7. Go to Development Certificate tab
8. Create a new Dev. Certificate providing the previous key produced (com.dir.app.dev)
9. Download the certificate produced and install inside local machine Keychain. Now the key appear to be certified with the downloaded certificate
10. Export the certificated as com.dir.app.dev.p12

**Provisioning creation**

11. [dev-console] Create a new mobile provisioning for dev (iOS App Development) selecting the appID - Here a problem occurs: **apple provide a certificates list** without showing ANY details about certificates - instead, for production certificates, an expired date as detail is shown. So i tried to perform various tests.
12. Export it as com.dir.app.dev.mobileprovision

**App Key creation**

13. [dev-console] - Go go the Keys tab
14. Create a new key
15. Download the new key as com.dir.app.key.p8

**Firebase configuration**

16. Create a new application calling it with the same name of app ID created at point 1 (com.dir.app)
17. Go to the Cloud messaging tab
18. Select the application com.dir.app
19. Insert the new APNS key produced in .p8 format with its ID

**Phonegap configuration**

20. Add a new key using as .p12 the file produced at point 10 (com.dir.app.dev.p12), as provisioning file produced at point 12 (com.dir.app.dev.mobileprovision) with respective password.

---

**Assumptions**

1. [Phonegap] - Phonegap build finish correctly and keys are correctly selected
2. [Backend] - The backend system is currently working with another application (for which iOS configuration are suspects ...)
3. [Token for Push] - The Token is correctly generate by the backend system

   ---

**Problem**

The push notifications are not received by the app installed on ad iPad with iOS 11.2.2

---

**QUESTIONS**

1. During the configuration of Phonegap, i have to provide the .p12 file for the push notification instead the development p12 certificate exported?
2. I have another application that inside the App ID tab (in the developer console), doesn't have the Push Notification SSL certificates configured: **how is possible that this application (eg. com.dir.alpha) is able to receive the push notification? Is there maybe another way to enable push?

Many thanks in advance.

Simon

Comment: Please do not add tags to your question title, including `[solved]` tags, as it may be perceived as unneeded noise by the community. When an answer is accepted, this is an acceptable way to show that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved resolving this one [Firebase + Push + iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48500927/firebase-push-ios?noredirect=1#comment83995708_48500927)

Based on your system GCM management, after having being sure to have configured properly your GCM creation and registration, you must have to being sure also to are able to send a push by the Firebase > Notification console selecting "Single Device" as push device target.