# Firebase + Push + iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-notifications

We encountering a problem during the push notification send in firebase.

Currently we have done these steps:-

1. We created a new app ID com.company.appname.country (without
   assigning it the push notification service)
2. We have create a development certificate for the app id
   com.company.appname.country (this creating a sign key request from local
   keychain)
3. We have create a create a sign key to create the development SSL
   certificate for the push notification (using the same key request
   created in the step 2)
4. We have download and install all certificate inside the local current
   keychain
5. We have create a development mobileprovision for the app
   com.bossitalia.gobooking.ch selecting all certificates avaialble
6. We have create a local project with XCode selecting the development
   mobileproviion file and the com.bossitalia.gobooking.ch certificated
   created in the point 2
7. After having build successfully problem relates to the notification
   is still present.

NB: in this configuration, Firebase application (com.company.appname.country) was configured in the "Cloud Messaging" setting tab by the SSL certificates (both for development and production - aka .p12)

Another test that we tried to do is to configure Firebase application without SSL certificates, but by adopting the current existing API key (created in the developer console).

Also in this last test, notifications seem to not work.

A final test was conduct inside Firebase > Notification tab, where in, when we set a test message for the ios device, a message error

> Registration token not registered

compare on the same line of iOS device.

What's can be the problem?

Comment: I used the new Authentication Keys method instead of the old p12 files. You can read more in the Firebase documentation, just follow their steps and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No the problem was relates to a wrong registration step inside the device. 

Simply we had in the table other token that didn't exist. 

The problem is that in this situation, Firebase didn't continue to iterante on the other GCM ids, simply appeared to stop to work. 
Anyway, a well formed local installation of a Firebase server console will can answer at this question.

Anyway after the table erasing, GCM system started to work properly.

Thanks